# F# - How can I divide an integer into (mostly equal) ‘buckets’ better than this?

Tags: list, f#, integer, divide

I have an integer number which I would like to divide into a list of integer ‘buckets’ of as-near-as-possible equal sizes.
Some examples:

- Dividing 10 by 2 should give me a list as “[ 5; 5 ]” (5+5=10), or,
- Dividing 20 by 3 should give me a list as “[ 7; 7; 6 ]” (7+7+6=20), or,
- Dividing 15 by 4 should give me a list as “[ 4; 4; 4; 3 ]” (4+4+4+3), that sort of thing.

It doesn’t matter if the larger buckets are at either end or the middle or mixed in – it’s to divide up a process for concurrent processing and the order is irrelevant.

I have written some code which seems to work okay but it seems too messy and is difficult to reason:

```
let integerBuckets total divider =
    match total, divider with
    | 0, _  -> [ 0 ]
    | 1, _ -> [ 1 ]
    | _, 0 -> [ total ] // Should  never happen, but checked just in case.
    | _, 1 -> [ total ]
    | _ ->
        let result = (double total) / (double divider)
        let remainder = total % divider
        [ for _ in 0 .. (remainder - 1) -> int (ceil result) ]
            @ [ for _ in 0 .. (divider - remainder - 1) -> int (floor result) ]

integerBuckets 15 4
```

I really don’t like the maths in the for loops; so easy to make a mistake and/or change by accident. But it’s not just the maths bit that I’m not sure of.

Can anyone give me some pointers as to how I can ‘tidy it up’ into better F# that reads more easily?

I am not asking for someone to supply a better code snippet, rather I am asking for pointers towards areas that I should be looking at to learn to make the code better myself.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do in the second part but you can match on both total and divider in the same expression `match total,divider with | 0,0 -> `, that will shorten it a bit

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that @onemorecupofcoffee. Refactoring as you recommended showed me a nasty flaw in the logic which has been (I hope) rectified. I’ve updated the code above as necessary. The rest of the code is the part which calculates the ‘buckets’ and is the main thing I would like advice on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the approach below would work. Basically, I generate a list of quotients and then distribute 1 unit of the remainder along the list until it is fully consumed.

```
let integerBuckets total divider =
    let rem = total % divider
    let quo = total / divider
    let dividerList = [1..divider]
    [ for _ in dividerList do yield quo ]  //create list of quotients
    |> List.map2 (+) [for i in dividerList do if i <= rem then 1 else 0] //distribute remainder
```

EDIT:

The function described above can be summarized as follows:

```
let integerBuckets2 total divider =
    let rem,quo = total % divider,total / divider
    [ for i in [1..divider] do yield if i <= rem then quo + 1 else quo ]
```

Comment: Thanks for that. There’s some code in there of the sort that I’ve not come across yet (I’m still very much a beginner) so I will need time to understand it but it looks much nicer than my original. At first glance I think I like the look of the second piece of code best but I need to understand both. Thanks again.

Comment: Both of these approaches are way better than the one I originally had and, now I understand (up to a point) what they are doing, they are both much easier to read. The first version, the one using the map2, takes around twice as long to execute - average time for 1,000,000 repetitions over five separate runs, approx. 1.1 seconds versus 0.6 seconds – so I think I would go with the second version in time-sensitive code. Either way though, nice code. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a more data-oriented approach to the problem to splitting up jobs for processing. If you store the items to process in an array then you can manipulate them with array functions. Here are some possible ways of doing that:

```
let chunkByChunkCount array chunkCount =
    let chunkSize = 
        (float (Array.length array) / float chunkCount)
        |> ceil
        |> int
    array |> Array.chunkBySize chunkSize

chunkByChunkCount [| 1 .. 15 |] 4
// [|[|1; 2; 3; 4|]; [|5; 6; 7; 8|]; [|9; 10; 11; 12|]; [|13; 14; 15|]|]



let dealIntoChunks array chunkCount =
    array
    |> Array.indexed
    |> Array.groupBy (fun (i, _) -> i % chunkCount)
    |> Array.map snd
    |> Array.map (Array.map snd)

dealIntoChunks [| 1 .. 15 |] 4
// [|[|1; 5; 9; 13|]; [|2; 6; 10; 14|]; [|3; 7; 11; 15|]; [|4; 8; 12|]|]
```

Comment: Thanks for that. As with the previous answer, and to a greater extent, there’s a lot for me to take in there and try to understand. I’m not totally sure how I will be doing the processing but I think your answer may come closer to what I will eventually need. The overall process will be quite complicated (at least for a beginner) so I’m trying ‘baby steps’ at the moment. Again, thanks for giving me another way to look at this, it’s very much appreciated.